# How to execute auxiliary script with main script's variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main python script I am running (which is quite lengthy), so I've compartmentalized sections of it into different python scripts. I *thought* any variables declared in the main script would be considered global to the auxiliary scripts (as long as the main script is calling the aux ones), but I'm running into issues. Here is a simplified example:

mainscript.py:

```
import auxscript

a = 1
auxscript.auxscript()
```

auxscript.py:

```
def auxscript():
    print("the value of a is: %s" %a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    auxscript()
```

What is the proper way to do this? I would have expected auxscript to first look locally for a, and then after not finding it, look globally within the scope it's launched from (mainscript.py)

Edit: I know I could obviously pass variables to the function through inputs, but I was hoping not to have to do this. It becomes messy when there are many variables that need to be accessed by the auxiliary scripts.

Comment: why not pass arguments from function to function?

Comment: And there is an error running your script as is? What was it?

Comment: @JacobIRR , sorry tried to add some clarification as I realized that would be the obvious way to do that. The main point of the auxiliary script is to reduced the length / clutter of the main script--the portion of the code I'm offloading is pretty static. It access many variables in the main script though. It doesn't make much sense in my mind to pass 20 variables to this function

Comment: @Reedinationer error:

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Have you considered using an IDE like PyCharm? You can have lengthy functions and classes that are minimized to one line with the push of a button.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that, I haven't been the biggest fan of Spyder.
Regardless, I'd like to pinpoint where my misunderstanding is of how the compiler is interpreting all of this. What happens when auxscript is called? Is the following wrong: "I would have expected auxscript to first look locally for a, and then after not finding it, look globally within the scope it's launched from (mainscript.py)"

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a through to your function like this.

mainscript.py:

```
import auxscript

a = 1
auxscript.auxscript(a)
```

auxscript.py

```
def auxscript():
    print("the value of a is: %s" %a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    auxscript(a)
```

Functions can generally only access variables passed to them or created within them.

Edit: Saw your edit. Why not use the above functionality but instead of passing a long list of variables you could pass a dictionary using **args. Then they will be read as keyword variables by your function.

Comment: He edited the post to add "I was hoping not to have to do this" with regard to passing variables to his functions